# How can I plot the spectrogram of a wav file without using predefined functions?

Tags: matlab, wav, speech

How can I plot the spectrogram of a WAV file without using predefined function?
i mean i dont want use FFT or spectrogram functions .

my windows i want to take over the whole signal should be Hamming windows .

could you please give me some advice ?

best regards .

i tried it for DFT . but i got error

```
n=256;
wholeFile=wavread('C:\Users\alireza\Desktop\alireza bahrami\New folder\Sound clip     32.wav');

for ii = 1:4096
waveform = wholeFile(128*ii + (1:256)); % a bit of background noise...

alpha = 0.54; beta = 1 - alpha; % hamming coefficients
hwin = alpha - beta * cos(2 * pi * (1:n) / (n - 1)); % from http://en.wikipedia.org    /wiki/Window_function#Hamming_window
fSample = 8192; % sampling frequency

t = (0.5:1:n) / fSample; % actual time


waveformHW = waveform .* hwin; % the windowed form of the waveform

frequencies = (0:(n/2)-1) * fSample / n;
myFFT = zeros(size(frequencies));
 for fi = 1:n/2
c = cos(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
s = sin(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
myFFT(fi) = (sum(c .* waveformHW) + 1i * sum(s .* waveformHW))/sum(c.*c.*hwin);
end
end
figure; semilogy(frequencies, abs(myFFT))
xlim([0 1000])
xlabel 'frequency'
ylabel 'amplitude'
title 'two tones plus noise'
```

the error : 
??? Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Hamilton windows ? Do you mean Hamming windows ? Anyway, if this is homework then you'll need to implement the window function, FFT, etc from scratch.

Comment: yes , HAMMING . from scratch?  what do you mean ?

Comment: Well the window is the easy part. Just create the envelope function and multiply your signal amplitude by the envelope (you can look up the exact form of the Hamming window online). As for rolling your own Fourier Transform - do you care if it's slow? Because a discrete fourier transform (DFT) can be coded in a handful of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can compute the DFT for an arbitrary waveform. It's slow but it works.
I have updated it so you can even see how to normalize (both amplitude and frequency).

Note - THIS IS SLOW. The "Fast Fourier Transform" got its name for a reason... By cleverly rearranging the calculation, it performs the same calculation as the one below, but much faster.

```
n = 4096;
waveform = 0.2*rand(1, n); % a bit of background noise...

alpha = 0.54; beta = 1 - alpha; % hamming coefficients
hwin = alpha - beta * cos(2 * pi * (1:n) / (n - 1)); % from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hamming_window
fSample = 8192; % sampling frequency

t = (0.5:1:n) / fSample; % actual time

% add some spectral components to the noise:
f1 = 440;    % Hz - A on the piano
f2 = 261.62; % Hz - middle C on the piano
waveform = waveform + 10 * cos(2 * pi * f1 * t) + 3 * cos(2 * pi * f2 * t);

waveformHW = waveform .* hwin; % the windowed form of the waveform

frequencies = (0:(n/2)-1) * fSample / n;
myFFT = zeros(size(frequencies));
for fi = 1:n/2
  c = cos(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
  s = sin(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
  myFFT(fi) = (sum(c .* waveformHW) + 1i * sum(s .* waveformHW))/sum(c.*c.*hwin);
end
figure; semilogy(frequencies, abs(myFFT))
xlim([0 1000])
xlabel 'frequency'
ylabel 'amplitude'
title 'two tones plus noise'
```

Now tested and (believed to be) working:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the tone that falls exactly in a bin (440 Hz) has exactly the right amplitude. The one that falls between two bins (261.62 Hz) looks too low - this is because the energy ends up spread among several bins in the spectrogram. There is an initial fast fall-off, and then a rather broad (if very low amplitude) residual. This is called "spectral leakage" - you will notice that it doesn't occur on the 440 Hz signal which is exactly on top of a bin. This is an inevitable consequence of the way this calculation is done. One nice thing about the DFT is that you do not need the frequencies to be evenly spaced - so you could, for example, compute this with the "exact frequencies of the piano", and this "partial binning" problem would go away.

But using the FFT is much faster.

Note also that the scale is now correct - both for amplitude and frequency. You can adjust the number of samples and the sampling frequency, and the scaling will follow along.

Do check that the math is right... don't use this for "real work", but only to understand the underlying principles.

Did I mention that this is much slower than an FFT?

Comment: thanks dear @Floris . i tested it but i had this error :
    ??? Error using ==> mtimes
    Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
what should i do ?

Comment: See edit - `*` should have been `.*` . Does that fix it?

Comment: i changed every * to .* but still no success :(

Comment: thanks dear @Floris . it really was helpful . but i should take my windows with size 256 and 50% overlap . how can i do that ? 
should i take n=256 ?
and i did not understand this : fSample = 8192; % sampling frequency

best regards . you're excellent

Comment: and can i read my wav file and put it to waveform ? and how ? because i had error :

??? Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: fSample = sample frequency. If you want to process just 256 points at a time with 50% overlap, you need to read in the entire file into a variable (say `wholeFile`), then take `waveform=wholeFile(128*ii + (1:256))` where you do `for ii = 1:someBigNumber`. Otherwise you set `n=256;` and `fSample` to whatever sampling frequency (usually in the file header). Try it. Post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: dear @floris i tried it and gor error .: ??? Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.
The code is in the following question !

Answer (score 0):

```
n=256;
wholeFile=wavread('C:\Users\alireza\Desktop\alireza bahrami\New folder\Sound clip     32.wav');

for ii = 1:4096
waveform = wholeFile(128*ii + (1:256)); % a bit of background noise...

alpha = 0.54; beta = 1 - alpha; % hamming coefficients
hwin = alpha - beta * cos(2 * pi * (1:n) / (n - 1)); % from http://en.wikipedia.org  /wiki/Window_function#Hamming_window
fSample = 8192; % sampling frequency

t = (0.5:1:n) / fSample; % actual time

% add some spectral components to the noise:
%f1 = 440;    % Hz - A on the piano
%f2 = 261.62; % Hz - middle C on the piano
%waveform = waveform + 10 * cos(2 * pi * f1 * t) + 3 * cos(2 * pi * f2 * t);

waveformHW = waveform .* hwin; % the windowed form of the waveform

frequencies = (0:(n/2)-1) * fSample / n;
myFFT = zeros(size(frequencies));
for fi = 1:n/2
c = cos(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
s = sin(2*pi*frequencies(fi) * t);
myFFT(fi) = (sum(c .* waveformHW) + 1i * sum(s .* waveformHW))/sum(c.*c.*hwin);
end
end
figure; semilogy(frequencies, abs(myFFT))
xlim([0 1000])
xlabel 'frequency'
ylabel 'amplitude'
title 'two tones plus noise'
```

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers… The error you were getting is a basic Matlab error - if you can't debug that I think you have come to the wrong place. Also, you need to ask yourself what you want to do with multiple spectrograms, because right now the way you modified the code overwrites them each time so you end up with just the last one. I suspect the problem is in the shape of `wholeFile`. If that is a column vector, then you need to transpose before using it. Type `whos` after you get the error and look at the shape / size of all variables; the problem should be obvious.